# What is reason of PrematureCloseException?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am using spring WebFlux, and I am using WebClient,
and it is working well, I saw two times I had this error in my logs, how can I know this connection issue happened in my side(client side) or the server side closed the connection, I copy error here:

```
reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException: Connection prematurely closed DURING response
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException
```

My Code which is client side is same as this code:

```
public void consumeServerSentEvent() {
WebClient client = WebClient.create("http://SERVER-IP:SERVER-PORT/PATH_TO_API");
ParameterizedTypeReference<ServerSentEvent<String>> type
 = new ParameterizedTypeReference<ServerSentEvent<String>>() {};

Flux<ServerSentEvent<String>> eventStream = client.get()
  .uri("/stream-sse")
  .retrieve()
  .bodyToFlux(type);

eventStream.subscribe(
  content -> logger.info("Time: {} - event: name[{}], id [{}], content[{}] ",
    LocalTime.now(), content.event(), content.id(), content.data()),
  error -> logger.error("Error receiving SSE: {}", error),
  () -> logger.info("Completed!!!"));
```

}

Comment: any luck @Fariba? had similar cases and only "retry", so kind-of-a-workaround did the work